# Can Azure VM activity be tracked by work?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, firewall, azure

My work blocks a bunch of sites on my laptop and I'm wondering if I access them through an Azure Machine if work can see what sites I'm visiting that way?

Comment: Yes.  Everything you do at work can be tracked. If a website is blocked at work, accept that fact, and wait to visit that website outside of work

Comment: @Ramhound. How can the work know the website traffic inside the RDP? Except  that  the network admin can monitor the OP's screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the ethical implications:

An Azure Virtual Machine is going to have its own pipe to the internet, having nothing to do with your local network. That applies to dns lookups too: Azure VMs are not going to use your local network's dns servers (assuming your local network had dns servers).

That said: you need *some* way of connecting to your Azure VM, whether that's RDP, an vpn, or some other desktop sharing tool. And there's no telling what type of monitoring your company is doing, regarding software you're running locally.

One more thing: If you're using an Azure subscription owned by / billed to the company you work for, they can easily track resource usage (virtual machines, storage, bandwidth, etc.). So if you spin up a VM in their subscription, there's a chance they'll be able to track general usage patterns, and may potentially be able to infer non-work-related resource usage.

Answer (score 1):

According to the RDP session is encrypted with the RC4 128-bit encryption algorithm, so, your work cannot see what sites you're visiting with Azure VM. But your work can know that you're using RDP.